# C# How to use get, set and use enums in a class

Tags: c#, class, enums, int, boolean

I have a program where I use a class store settings. I need it to use set and get functions to change and store settings. I have tried this, and I don't get it to work. Can anyone help me with this one?

```
    private enum _Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard };

    public void SetDifficulty(Difficulty)
    {
        _Difficulty = Difficulty;
    }

    public enum GetDifficulty()
    {
        return _Difficulty;
    }
```

Is there no way to use `enums` in a class with `get` and `set`?

I also need this with `bool` and `int`.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding of basic C# concepts here that I'm not sure any answer can solve. What was your starting point for this?

Comment: An enum isn't a variable - its a type. You can't use it to store information that changes at runtime.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There are several things wrong here:

- Your enum is private, but your methods are public. Therefore you can't make your methods return type be the enum type, or have parameters with that type
- Your `SetDifficulty` method has a parameter of just `Difficulty` - is that meant to be the parameter name or the type?
- Your `SetDifficulty` method is trying to set the *type* rather than a field
- Your `GetDifficulty` method is trying to use `enum` as a return type, and is then returning a *type* rather than a field

Basically, you seem to be confused about what your `enum` declaration is declaring - it's not declaring a *field*, it's declaring a *type* (and specifying what the named values of that type are).

I suspect you want:

```
// Try not to use nested types unless there's a clear benefit.
public enum Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard }

public class Foo
{
    // Declares a property of *type* Difficulty, and with a *name* of Difficulty
    public Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }
}
```

You can use get/set methods if you really want to make your code look like Java instead of C#:

```
public enum Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard }

public class Foo
{
    private Difficulty difficulty;

    public void SetDifficulty(Difficulty value)
    {
        difficulty = value;
    }

    public Difficulty GetDifficulty()
    {
        return difficulty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon, I like the first variation with the public property, but am having trouble with naming it. Can you suggest a good naming convention for this type of thing?

Comment: @LouiseEggleton: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Naming the variation? Naming the property? Naming the class containing the property?

Comment: Naming the class containing the property in the case where the only purpose of the containing class is to set the enum. I use this pattern in cases where I want to have a constructor for the enum and of course enums can't have constructors so I contain them in a class.Calling the class in this case DifficultySetter or something along those lines seems lame.

Comment: @LouiseEggleton: That would feel like a slightly odd class, to be honest. The context here was "a class storing settings" suggesting that it wouldn't be just this one property. I think I'd need to see a lot more context of a real situation to advise on a name.

Answer (score 6):

You code tries to assign `Difficulty` a value, when in fact `Difficulty` is the name of the `enum` type. I would encourage use of getters and setters as properties instead:

```
public enum Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard };

private Difficulty _difficulty;

public Difficulty CurrentDifficulty
{
    get { return _difficulty; }
    set { _difficulty = value; }
}
```

This way you can add additional code in the setter for special conditions. To use it you simply do the following:

```
//set
CurrentDifficulty = Difficulty.Easy;

//get
Difficulty theDifficulty = CurrentDifficulty;
```

Answer (score 5):

Once you specify an enum using the `enum` keyword, that enum acts as a type, like a `class` or `struct` would.

Here's how you'd implement a property with a custom enum:

```
public enum _Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard };
public _Difficulty Difficulty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The enum you want to use needs to be public. You also need an instance of that enum to store the value you're setting, you're currently setting it to your enum's declaration. Then you want to use the same enum type for what your class stores and what you pass in.

```
public enum Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard };

public Difficulty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here:

1. Your `enum` is private, so nothing will be able to call `SetDifficulty` to provide it with a value from that `enum`.  Indeed, the compiler won't allow this.
2. The argument to `SetDifficulty` is just a type, it also needs a variable name.  Also a compiler error.
3. You're trying to get/set the value of the enumeration itself, rather than a class-level variable of the type of the enumeration.  This too won't compile.

It *looks like* you want to do this:

```
public enum Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard }

public Difficulty DifficultySetting { get; set; }
```

Note that I had to change the name of the property to `DifficultySetting` because it conflicts with the enum name.  Yours used an underscore, which would also solve that problem.  However I always found that underscores are for private members and if you want consuming code to use this `enum` then it would need to be public.  Decorating a public member with things like underscores distracts from the semantics of the name itself.  In any event, the semantics are up to your personal preference, so you can modify these names as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are using them correctly. This might help...

```
private enum Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard };
private Diffuculty theDifficulty;

public void SetDifficulty(difficulty d)
{
    theDifficulty = difficulty;
}

public Difficulty GetDifficulty()
{
    return theDifficulty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a *type* not a *variable*.  Something like this would work:

```
public enum Difficulty { Easy, Normal, Hard };

private Difficulty _Difficulty;

public void SetDifficulty(Difficulty difficulty )
{
    _Difficulty = Difficulty;
}

public Difficulty GetDifficulty()
{
    return _Difficulty;
}
```

or more succinctly as an Auto Property:

```
private Difficulty Difficulty {get; set;}
```

Note that the enum has to be `public` if you want it to be accessible from public methods.