# Implementing an abstract Enum property in a child class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, enumeration

I have the following base class

```
public abstract class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected abstract Enum CurrentState
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

and the following child class

```
public class Player : Character
{
    protected override Enum CurrentState
    {
        get
        {
            return (State)_anim.GetInteger("State");
        }
        set
        {
           _anim.SetInteger("State", Convert.ToInt32(value));
        }
    }

    private enum State
    {
        IDLE = 0,
        WALK = 1,
        JUMP = 2,
        FALL = 3,
        CLIMB = 4,
        LOOKING_DOWN = 5,
        NPC = 6,
        IMPATIENT = 7,
        LOOKING_UP = 8,
        STUCK = 9,
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (CurrentState == State.CLIMB)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

The line

```
if (CurrentState == State.CLIMB)
```

yields the following error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Enum' and 'Player.State'

Any help? The getter works fine. So maybe I need to do a cast conversion in the set accessor? I'm not really sure...I'm kind of new to this...Any help would be more than appreciated.

Comment: try changing private enum to public enum that is outside of your class object

Comment: What is confusing you?  `CurrentState` is type `Enum`, `State.Climb` is type `State`

Comment: a concise answer for enum catch22's located here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335103/c-sharp-how-to-use-get-set-and-use-enums-in-a-class

Comment: you can see how to compare enums here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537083/c-sharp-enum-how-to-compare-value

Comment: I think you want a CurrentState property that sets/gets a value of type State. CurrentState shouldn't be an enum.

Comment: Does each character have its own state type? If so, you could make `Character` generic, i.e. `Character<TState>` with `CurrentState` of type `TState`. Specific types could then specify a type for `TState`, which could be whatever you like, incl. enum.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing an `Enum` with `State`. Which is illegal. You return type for ***CurrentState*** should be ***State***. Something like -

```
protected override State CurrentState
{
    get
    {
        return (State)_anim.GetInteger("State");
    }
    set
    {
       _anim.SetInteger("State", Convert.ToInt32(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in previous post, illegal operation of Enum. Do not do that.

```
 namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        public enum State
        {
            IDLE = 0,
            WALK = 1,
            JUMP = 2,
            FALL = 3,
            CLIMB = 4,
            LOOKING_DOWN = 5,
            NPC = 6,
            IMPATIENT = 7,
            LOOKING_UP = 8,
            STUCK = 9,
        }

        public abstract class Character : MonoBehaviour
        {
            protected abstract State CurrentState
            {
                get;
                set;
            }
        }


        public class MonoBehaviour
        {
        }

        public class Player : Character
        {      

            protected override State CurrentState
            {
                get
                {
                    return (State)_anim.GetInteger("State");
                }
                set
                {
                    _anim.SetInteger("State", Convert.ToInt32(value));
                }
            }



            void FixedUpdate()
            {
                if (CurrentState == State.CLIMB)
                {

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: So if another object besides Player inherits from Character, where should that object define its states?

Comment: Enums can be namespaced to give clarity to which one you need. You can put them anywhere you want but keep in mind enum helps for clarity in your code as to which integer value you are expecting in English.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(CurrentState) == Convert.ToInt32(State.CLIMB))
            { 

            }
```

As Enum's cannot be compared as types you need to convert them for comparing.

Comment: Why convert and not just cast?

Comment: That works, but I can't keep converting both sides of the argument to int32 everytime there's an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

If I replace the property with two different accessors, it seems to work...

```
protected override Enum SetCurrentState
{
    set
    {
        _anim.SetInteger("State", Convert.ToInt32(value));
    }
}

private bool GetCurrentState(State state)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32((State)_anim.GetInteger("State")) == Convert.ToInt32(state);
}
```